# GooglePlay-Complaint SMS Design

Tags: android, user-interface, google-play, sms

I'm looking for UI design help for an Android SMS messaging app that'll satisfy the following:

1. User shall be able to send basic SMS messages to contact(s)
2. A background service shall send an SMS to our servers once every 24 hrs
3. User may enable/disable items 1 & 2 above except enabling #1 requires #2 to be enabled. If disabled, prompt when user tries to send a message.
4. App must satisfy the [Google Play Developer Policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html#spam), specifically: "Do not send SMS, email, or other messages on behalf of the user without providing the user with the ability to confirm content and intended recipient." (10/06/15)

The root of my problem lies in item #4 above - When do I have to prompt the user, how often, etc? I've contacted Google Play Developer Support multiple times & received a generic response w/ a copy-paste of #4 above. To help structure this question I've come up with the following questions regarding UI design:

- Q1: How to satisfy both requirements #2 and #4 w/out prompting every single time the background service wants to send an SMS?
- Q2: How to satisfy both requirements #1 and #4 w/ the minimal amount of prompting? (e.g. if prompting's required, is a remember-my-choice checkbox okay?)
- Q3: Same as Q2 but include requirement #3 as well.

Please note that any SMS sent by the background service is done so on a zero-rated number (like a 1.800 line for sms) so any&all costs are incurred by the app creator rather than the dude with the android phone. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: We have no way of telling you what will and will not satisfy Google's policies, as we are not Google.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. There are many Android applications which use SMS, all of which have experience complying with these policies. If anyone has such experience this is a great medium for us to share solutions.

Comment: No, it would be to share opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your broad question of, "When do I have to prompt the user, how often, etc?" is pure speculation unless Google provides a specific answer. You are creating a "messaging app" and you are interested in "UI design help" as it pertains to the policy and your app requirements, which is difficult without explaining a lot about your app.

However, as a messaging app it's critical that your UI make clear the content of a message and the intended recipient. If you don't do that well, Google policy is a moot point. Similarly, the purpose and functionality of a "remember my choice" checkbox, in your question, had better be clear to the user.

So the real concerns you have are the "background service sending an SMS to a server" and then "linking" that to a contact. The key for these is user awareness, which is more of a UX question than a UI question.

For example, you need to inform the user of the server SMS even before the first one is sent. How you present the warning will depend on the experience you are trying to provide - Google does not restrict this from being in a game format, does not require the user to "retype" the agreement statements or have them both check a box and click an "agree" button. Those decisions are left to us as developers.

And the continued sending of messages must be clear. So even with an initial warning message to users Google may determine that your notification was not sufficient to meet their guideline. You should not expect Google to be more specific.

Google has done us a favor by not trying to specify UI or UX with their policy. To state all requirements in anticipation of what developers may imagine could severely restrict developer creativity or have negative unintended consequences.

This is where @CommonsWare is indicating that you are asking about opinions. Is is unknown what criteria Google may apply. There are simply too many UI/UX variants. The policy requires you to provide information and the burden is on you to make it a good experience.

Some UI/UX examples that might help you:

- Provide an upfront notification with few words that explains what you
  are doing and have the user agree to it before you implement it.
- Make your policy available for reference in the app even after the user
  "agrees" to it.
- Provide periodic reminders based on time or number of
  messages sent.
- Provide an in-app log file containing the server
  messages.
- Add an occasional banner in the app.
- Have your server listed as a "contact" so the messages to it are as clear as to other recipients, etc.

Implementing some or all of these is still no guarantee of nonviolation. They may not be implemented well or you may have a separate violation, but I hope that helps address your concerns.

Also, although it helps that you do not charge the user, Google policy does not exclude or indicate leniency for that situation. I would recommend that you do not treat is as being a more lenient case although users may appreciate it.

If you have an honest app that is genuinely trying to help and/or entertain the user, and it does that by providing data back to your servers on a periodic basis and the user is OK with that, then Google would probably be OK with it, too. They want quality apps on Google Play that users like. Always try to make it very clear to the user who is receiving messages (and data) and the content.

If, on the other hand, you are asking, "What is the least I can do without getting my app pulled?" or "How can I appear to comply without really complying?" then there is not much I (or anyone else) can do to "help" you.

Comment: Thanks, this is was very helpful